# Backup: How to place output of 'split' on external drive?

Tags: linux, backup, tar, hard-drive

I am trying to back up ("copy") my home directory to an external hard drive so that I can send the computer in for repairs. Naturally, the family external HD is FAT32, which means I have a max filesize of 2G.

I have a few files which are greater than 2G - some tarballs, VM images, etc. I figure the easiest thing to do is to use `split` to split up these files into FAT32-friendly chunks.

My question is: I don't have enough space on my HD to split each file and store the component parts. I want to do something like `split bigfile.tar -o /mnt/external_drive`, but the man page doesn't seem to indicate such an option.

What would be the best way to manage this?

Alternately, I could just tar-up /home/rascher, but that has the same problem - I don't have enough local disk space to retain a copy of the tarball, and if I try `tar -cvzf /mnt/external_drive/backup.tar ./` then I will run into the same 2G boundary.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you ask the vendor if you can send the computer without the disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the backup:

```
tar cf - /home/rascher | split -b 2000m - /mnt/external_drive/backup/rascher_home
```

and the restore:

```
cat /mnt/external_drive/backup/rascher_home* | ( cd / && tar xf - )
```

This way you don't use up twice the disk space (no need to create bigfile.tar.)

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me to place a path in split's "PREFIX" option. This worked beautifully, thanks so much.

Comment: for my own reference: `cat myarchive* | ( cd /home/rascher/testuntar/2 && tar --extract home/rascher/testtar/.e )` extracts a specific item.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
$ cd /mnt/external_drive && split /path/to/original/bigfile.tar
```